# how to upgrade to graph api version 2.0 for this call

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

i'm doing this request on my website to facebook:
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=12345

i now wonder how this call would look like if i want to make it in a "API version2.0" way?

I've read this upgrade article of facebook https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading?locale=en_GB

but couldn't find any matching example.

Thanks in advance,
Phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be try the request like following :
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/oauth/access_token?client_id=12345...